# Indian passport expiring in 4 months

Tags: customs-and-immigration, passports, indian-citizens

I am an Indian citizen with a current Indian passport. I booked a ticket to India to travel in 2 weeks time. When I wanted to enter my passport details for online check-in, it wouldn’t let me proceed any further as the passport will expire in March. Will India still let me in?

I am travelling from Australia through Singapore to India. Would I be ok at the airport or get denied to travel? Can someone help?

Comment: Your own country will always let you in, even with no documents whatsoever (though verifying your identity will take a while then).

Comment: Thank you so much for your reply